# Get the uploaded file attribute from one servlet to other servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, file-upload

I have Java application with two servlets. The first servlet will upload the file. And the second one is to retrive the uploaded file.

I am able to upload the file and forwarding it to second servlet. But when i tried to retrieve th file getting null pointer exception. How to retrieve the file attribute in the second servlet.

What i have tried for forwarding from Serv1 to Serv2 for retrieving the uploaded file

Serv1.java:

```
private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "../AISNMEA/WebContent/WEB-INF/resources";

public String file1;
String filePath;
String uploadFilePath;
UploadFile upfile;
String fileName;
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // set location for saving uploaded file
        UploadBean upb = new UploadBean();

        upb.setFolderstore(UPLOAD_DIR);
        upb.setFilesizelimit(1073741824);
        upb.setOverwrite(true);

        MultipartFormDataRequest nreq = new MultipartFormDataRequest(
                request);
        // completed file uploading
        upb.store(nreq);
        Hashtable<?, ?> ht = nreq.getFiles();// gives the uploaded file
        Enumeration<?> e = ht.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            upfile = (UploadFile) e.nextElement();
            uploadFilePath = UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator;
            File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
            if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
                fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
            }
            file1 = UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator + upfile.getFileName();
            filePath = new File(file1).getAbsolutePath();
            fileName = upfile.getFileName()
                    .substring(0, upfile.getFileName().indexOf("."))
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim().concat("_")
                    .concat("data");
        }            
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("fileName", filePath);
        RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/vdr.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Serv2.java:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/html");

    double base_x = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n1"));
    double base_y = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n2"));
    double m0 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n3"));
    double a = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n4"));
    double b = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n5"));
    double k1 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n6"));
    double k2 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n7"));
    double k3 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n8"));
    double k4 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n9"));
    double k5 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n10"));
    double k6 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n11"));
    double k7 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n12"));
    double k8 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n13"));
    double Lbp = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n14"));

    double ido00 = base_x * PI / 180.0;

    double keido00 = base_y * PI / 180.0;

    double s0 = k1 * ido00 + k2 * Math.sin(2.0 * ido00) + k3
            * Math.sin(4.0 * ido00) + k4 * Math.sin(6.0 * ido00) + k5
            * Math.sin(8.0 * ido00) + k6 * Math.sin(10.0 * ido00) + k7
            * Math.sin(12.0 * ido00) + k8 * Math.sin(14.0 * ido00);
    double f = 1.0 / 299.152813;
    double e2 = (Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2)) / Math.pow(a, 2);
    HttpSession session=req.getSession();
    filePath = (String) session.getAttribute("fileName");
    System.out.println("File Path" + filePath);
    doGet(req, res);
}
```

index.html:

```
<form action="ser1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
<input name="fileName" type="file"/>
</form>
```

vdr.html:

```
<form name="myForm" action="ser2" method="post"
    onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
</form>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can u put in session scope and try to get it from sessionscope ?? and request.setAttribute("fileName", "file"); the "file" is String.you need to put file reference i think.

Comment: Did you define an empty global request object? Your function is taking in a parameter called `request` but you are trying to read the attribute from a variable called `req`.

Comment: @developerwjk Yes, I have defined as HttpServletRequest httpreq = null; in Serv2.class and called as String filePath = (String) httpreq.getAttribute("fileName"); but getting the same null pointer exception.

Comment: @Naren I tried but getting the same null pointer exception

Comment: In your doGet and doPost methods you should read the parameters from the request object that is passed in as a parameter to the function, not from an empty global request. Then you wouldn't have to use session here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the `file name in request scope` , So it is available only in the `vdr.html`, not in the  `Serv2.java`.

If you save the `file name in session scope` , the file name will be available through out the `session`.

You have to do this like ,

**From ,**

```
 request.setAttribute("fileName", "file");
```

**To,**

```
 session.setAttribute("fileName", "file");
```

Then you can get the file name as ,

```
String filePath = (String) session.getAttribute("fileName");
```

Also one more additional info ,

Servlets are not thread-safe.So please try to declare the variables inside the doGet() and doPost().It is the good practice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have a web application to upload zip file which consists of 1000 files and generates a downloadable excel file. when i am reading the zip file which contains more than 1000 files getting "out of memory error".How to get out of it.